# Error while connecting swift server side with mongokitten

Tags: mongodb, swift3, vapor

[image]

Database constructor is throwing a complier error when connecting a mongodb server using the mongokitten, image is attached for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't used *MongoKitten* yet, but I got the same error in the last days using *Vapor*.

In my case it was because of *type inference* that didn't work because of generics. So I had to type something similar like this:

```
let database: Database = try Database("mongodb://localhost/reading_journal")
```

But if I look into the MongoKitten docs it turns out you don't have to use the `Database` class:

```
let server = try Server("mongodb://localhost:27017")
let database = server["reading_journal"]

if server.isConnected {
    print("Connected successfully to server")
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Marc for the solution